# Woocommerce wishlist plugin breaking cookies/cache?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce site right now. I have a plugin for the wishlist that I purchased from Code Canyone here - http://codecanyon.net/item/dvin-woocommerce-wishlist-wp-plugin/1995206

The issue is that when I activate the wishlist plugin I'm no longer able to add multiple items to the cart. It feels like the plugin is breaking the cachce or cookies in some way, and causing it to reset every time you click "add to cart"

I have found that even upon uploading and running without a modified theme or modified plugin in any way that it still doesn't work. I have looked online, but no one else is seeming to have this problem. So it must be me?

I don't get any errors regarding the cache or plugin with debug mode on. (I do get tons of errors for cForms, though. not sure why, but that's another post).

Take a look - http://www.shultzilla.com/admin/shop/sample-product/

Has anyone run into this issue before? Is this a symptom of a specific issue? I have no idea why this would only be happening to me and no one else.

If I deactivate the plugin it works fine, so I'm pretty sure it's something up with this plugin. I've tried to reach out to the developer, but I haven't heard back from him, and Code Canyon says they're not responsible.

Thanks in advance for your help, y'all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get ahold of the developer.

Turns out there was a session_start() function that was being called in two files.

He's fixed the issue and it now works.